# PySide instead of PyQt4 as the prerequisite for matplotlib Qt4Agg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyside

I have a quick question with regard to the prerequisite of using Qt4Agg backend with matplotlib. In the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend), it said Qt4Agg requires PyQt4. However, since matplotlib can now work perfectly with PySide instead of PyQt4, can I install PySide only? Do I still need to install PyQt4 to let matplotlib work with Pyside?

I am asking this question because in the [example](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/PySide) of using matplotlib with PySide, the backend has to be switched to Qt4Agg and requires PyQt4 according to the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `rcparam` file add the line

```
backend.qt4 : PySide        # PyQt4 | PySide
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to install Pyside. and then do something like this

```
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyside' 
from matplotlib import use
use('Qt4Agg') 
import pylab as plt
```

Comment: You can do this with rcparams with out the need to mess with environmental variables. On phone which makes looking up exact value name hard.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you don't want to modify the rcParam file:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('backend', qt4="PySide")
```